# bigQuery Google Cloud how to share dataset with other users?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigQuery dataset defined in Google Cloud with my userA account, and I want my colleague userB, who is a member of the same group, to be able to see the dataset that I have defined. Using the `bq` command-line interface, userB can see the project, but not the dataset. How can I share the dataset created by userA with userB?

Comment: did you have chance to read documentation? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#updating_dataset_access_controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Web UI of BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bigquery-web-ui#sharedataset), there is a dropdown menu to the right of the dataset's name. There, you can choose `Share Dataset`:

[image: BigQuery Web UI Share Dataset]

On the popup window, you'll be able to add Google Groups, Individual Users, or even Service Accounts. The permissions you'll be able to assign here are *Primitive* roles. As explained in the [BigQuery Web UI documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#bigquery-update-dataset-access-cli):

> "Can view" (READER) grants bigquery.dataViewer access to the dataset.
>
> "Can edit" (WRITER) grants bigquery.dataEditor access to the dataset.
>
> "Is owner" (OWNER) grants bigquery.dataOwner access to the dataset.

If you want to know more about BigQuery permissions, [you can check this link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#transitioning_from_primitive), it lists all currently available permissions.

Note that you can also do this [via bq](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#bigquery-update-dataset-access-cli) or directly via the [RESTful API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/get).

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer.

Comment: for the record, the new UI (as of 17 Oct 2018) does not have this "Share Dataset" dropdown. See "Limitations" https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#sharedataset

Comment: You can share a dataset with the console BigQuery web UI assigning IAM roles to the new members https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control

Answer (score 0):

There is a dropdown menu on the right of the dataset:

[image]

As explained in the Web UI documentation:

Click the drop-down arrow to the right of the dataset and choose Share Dataset.

In the Share Dataset dialog, to modify existing entries:

Remove existing entries by clicking the X icon to the right of the user, group, or service account.
Change permissions for a user, group, or service account by clicking the permissions button and choosing an appropriate access level: Is owner (OWNER), Can edit (WRITER), or Can view (READER). For more information on dataset-level roles, see Primitive roles for datasets.
In the Share Dataset dialog, to add new entries:

Click the drop-down to the left of the Add People field and choose the appropriate option.

Type a value in the text box. For example, if you chose User by e-mail, type the user's email address.

To the right of the Add People field, click Can view and choose the appropriate role from the list.

Add people to dataset

"Can view" (READER) grants bigquery.dataViewer access to the dataset.
"Can edit" (WRITER) grants bigquery.dataEditor access to the dataset.
"Is owner" (OWNER) grants bigquery.dataOwner access to the dataset.
Click Add.

When you are done adding, deleting, or modifying your access controls, click Save changes.

Verify your access controls by clicking the drop-down arrow to the right of the dataset and choosing Share Dataset. You can confirm the settings in the Share Dataset dialog.