# Big Query how to share a dataset in the new UI

Tags: user-interface, google-bigquery

When using the old big query UI a dataset can be shared as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911538/bigquery-google-cloud-how-to-share-dataset-with-other-users).

How can this be done using the new UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you can share a dataset in the new UI. Click a dataset, click "Share Dataset", and then configure the desired permission (use the "Viewer" permission to allow the person to write and run queries on the data).

[image: screenshot of sharing a dataset]

-Michael (PM for BigQuery)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is supported in new UI yet
It is not!

See current [`limitations`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#limitations):

> The beta release of the BigQuery web UI is subject to the following limitations
>
> Currently, you cannot use the BigQuery web UI to:
>       •   Work with the BigQuery Data Transfer Service
>       •   **Assign access controls to datasets**
>       •   Create a table protected using customer-managed encryption keys (CMEK) (you can still work with existing tables that were protected using a CMEK)
>       •   View a query's explanation plan while the query is running
>       •   View the query execution timeline
>       •   Navigate between the first and last page of query results
>       •   Display the pricing warning when you run a SELECT * SQL query
>       •   Add, edit, or delete labels for BigQuery resources
>       •   Share a saved query
>       •   Sort or filter your job history or query history